# NameError is not defined

Tags: python

Please bear with me as I'm still very new to programming. I am writing a python script that will login to a remote server and capture a string/text from a text file. I'm using pxssh as my module to achieve that. I tried running the script put it gives me an error that says **faultyhardware = getFaultyHardware()
NameError: name 'getFaultyHardware' is not defined**. I tried reading other issues in this site and I can't seem to get it at all. Can someone point me to the right direction on how to fix? Appreciate all the help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pxssh
import getpass

try:

s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
username = raw_input('username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
s.login (hostname, username, password)
s.sendline ('cat /home/ubuntu/output.txt')  
s.prompt()             
faultyhardware = getFaultyHardware(s.before)
for faulty in faultyhardware:
   print(faulty)
print s.before          
s.logout()

def getFaultyHardware(contents):

faulty = []
 content_list = contents.split(':')
 for x in range(len(content_list))
    is_exist = 'Location' in content_list[x]
    if is_exist == True:
      start = content_list[x+1].find("/")
      output = content_list[x+1][start:][:14]
      print(output)
      faulty.append(output)
return faulty
```

Comment: move your function definition above your try statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the function before you use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pxssh
import getpass

def getFaultyHardware(contents):

    faulty = []
     content_list = contents.split(':')
     for x in range(len(content_list))
        is_exist = 'Location' in content_list[x]
        if is_exist == True:
          start = content_list[x+1].find("/")
          output = content_list[x+1][start:][:14]
          print(output)
          faulty.append(output)
    return faulty

try:

s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
username = raw_input('username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
s.login (hostname, username, password)
s.sendline ('cat /home/ubuntu/output.txt')  
s.prompt()             
faultyhardware = getFaultyHardware(s.before)
for faulty in faultyhardware:
   print(faulty)
print s.before          
s.logout()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! Appreciate all the help. I'm really new into this thing and honestly was hesitant to ask at first because it might just be a simple question but I'm still happy that I did! All the best!

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help you. Keep on studying, trying, asking and learning...and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You should put the definition of `getFaultyHardware` before the `try` statements. Python is interpreted line by line so at the point of `try`, `getFaultyHardware` is not yet defined.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! Appreciate all the help. I'm really new into this thing and honestly was hesitant to ask at first because it might just be a simple question but I'm still happy that I did! All the best!